# How do I login the user with commands membership?

Tags: asp.net, membership

I want users my web site login with membership system.I use this commands for verify the validate username and  password , and then login the user.

```
Membership.ValidateUser("hmahdavi", "123456789");
        Membership.GetUser();
```

This codes is not  work correctly.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right but missing setting up form authentication cookies. just set the auth cookie.

```
       if (Membership.ValidateUser("hmahdavi", "123456789"))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("hmahdavi", true);
            Response.Write("Logged in!");
        }
```